# PL/pgSQL: cannot find output of "raise notice" statements

Tags: printing, plpgsql, raise

The stored procedure sp_test contains several print-statements such as:

```
raise notice 'TEST !!!!!!';
```

However, when I execute the following script:

```
select *                                                                             
  from sp_test  (v_par1 := 1,                                              
                v_debugmode := 1          );
```

... a result set is returned but I don't see anything of the "raise notice"-statements.

Where are these print-statements printed to (where can I find the output of these print statements)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on client and notification level. `psql` notices displays directly, pgAdmin in special tab. Check value of configuration variable `client_min_messages`. Is possible set filter, and notices are not send to client.